# How do i find all incoming arcs/edges of a certain node in this simple graph

Tags: python, graph, nodes, edges

I was reading through https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/ on how to implement graphs. The thing is, I am kind of confused on how to find all incoming arcs to a certain node in the fastest possible way.

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
             'B': ['C', 'D'],
             'C': ['D'],
             'D': ['C'],
             'E': ['F'],
             'F': ['C']}
```

I know that node C has arcs from node A, B, D, F directed to it. The problem is : how do I check nodes A, B, D, F without going into each list in the dictionary of keys to see if it contains C. Is there a better way to do this or a more efficient graph and method? Can someone point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Comment: The right data structure for your problem is an *adjacency matrix*, rather than an adjacency list. I believe for directed graphs it's called an "incidence matrix". It is more time efficient to check for specific arcs, but much less space efficient, especially with a sparse graph.

Comment: @machineyearning Do you happen to know any sites that teaches adjacency matrix for python and it's implementation that you can share? That will be really helpful, thanks in advance. Also whats the difference with adjacency matrix compare to the adjacency list?

Comment: You could also improve your performance by implementing your adjacency lists as `set` data structures. Then you could check set membership like `[pointsFrom for (pointsFrom, pointsTo) in graph.items() if target in pointsTo]`. That would give you order-n performance where n is the number of nodes in your graph.

Comment: Not offhand. Since you're interested in graph representations, I'd highly recommend you read and fully understand [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) before proceeding, once you do that your implementation problems will become pretty elementary in python. I'm gonna throw my `set` suggestion down below as an answer because it's what I'd do.

Answer (score 2):

You can get something similar to an adjacency matrix simply by using `set` structures

```
graph = {'A': {'B', 'C'},  # If you're using python 2.7+ you can initalize a set like this
         'B': {'C', 'D'},
         'C': {'D'},
         'D': {'C'},
         'E': set(['F']),  # Set initialization pre-2.7
         'F': set()}       # Empty set initialization, can't use {}
```

Then you can check for the nodes incident to `target` like:

```
[pointsFrom for (pointsFrom, pointsTo) in graph.items() if target in pointsTo]
```

This will have a running time linear in the number of nodes in your graph.

Comment: Can you explain how does `[pointsFrom for (pointsFrom, pointsTo) in graph.items() if target in pointsTo]` work? i know sets allow for comparing element inside the set, but how does this code work in layman term, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a really good syntax to be familiar with in python, called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's basically a shorthand for declaring a list, iterating through something, filtering the elements, and transforming them before adding them to your declared list. You can read it like `for each (pointsFrom, pointsTo) pair in graph.items(), if target is in the pointsTo set, put pointsFrom in my result list`. These expressions are **super useful** and can be used to create lists, dictionaries, or any kind of iterable structure.

Comment: In the general case this is called a (Generator Expression)[https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/] and produces an iterable that doesn't take up memory, generating one item at a time and `yield`ing it to some function that consumes an iterable. For example wrapping it in a `list` constructor gives you a `list`, same with a `dict` or `set` constructor. Study these and practice using them, it will help to keep your code clean, and very efficient and idiomatic. (edit: i don't know why the link markdown isn't working above)